# sql How to Count numbers

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want count numbers from column in table in database

This example:

[image]

`39 + 23 + 9 = 71` How I can Do that?

mysql code:

```
SELECT COUNT(column) as total from table
```

but it not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint:  `SUM()`, not `COUNT()`.

Comment: However, I would handle this particular problem in application code

Comment: Thanks for all.  yes  it is SUM, don't COUNT

Comment: ok @Shadow, I haven't used ROLLUP since msft days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT SUM(column) as total from table
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUM()` is your friend!

Check the w3school:

http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_func_sum.asp

Comment: Please don't refer to `w3schools` as `the manual`. Here's the manual, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum.

Comment: Ok, you have right !

Answer (score 0):

It is `SUM`, not `COUNT` 
use:

```
select SUM(views) from Your_tb_name
```

Comment: yes, you can accept me?

Comment: @ĐứcNguyễn Only 1 answer can be accepted. The other answers/comments were made awhile before yours and are the same.